# When iterating over a list using a for loop, why does "for x in range(len(spam)) work but not "for x in spam"?

Tags: python, loops

Coming from JS, looping over a list using a for loop does work as I would expect.

```
spam = ['bat', 'nap', 'hat']

 for x in spam:
    print(spam[x])
```

Prints the error
File "", line 2, in 
    print(spam[x])
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

While

```
for x in range(len(spam)):
    print(spam[x])
```

Prints out

```
bat
nap
hat
```

I understand now how to iterate over a list, but I am not totally sure on the logic of it. Why does

```
range(len(spam))
```

print the correct result? From the way I understand it, len(spam) is just returning an integer value (3) in this case, which then simplifies down to range(3)?

Maybe I just answered my own question - but is it because python now knows how many times to iterate over spam, with spam[x]?

Comment: `for x in spam : print (x)` ??

Comment: Did you repost this question?

Answer (score 1):

When you have

```
spam = ['bat', 'nap', 'crap']

 for x in spam:
    print(spam[x])
```

...in the first iteration of the loop you're asking for `print spam['bat']` which doesn't make any sense.

In the version that works, it's expanded to `for x in range(3)`, in which the first iteration would be `print spam[0]` which is correct.

if you want the index, use `enumerate`, otherwise just `print x` in your original code.

```
for i, entry in enumerate(spam):
  print spam[i]
  # or just "print entry"
```

Comment: total misunderstanding on my part. I get it now. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

try this, and things will become clear:

```
for x in spam:
    print(x)
```

Comment: yeah, now I see, way over thinking it

Answer (score 1):

For loops in python don't just work based on an index

```
for x in spam:
    print(x)
```

The above will work because the for loops iterates over each element in spam. X is each element not the index of the element in spam.

Your second one works because range returns a list of indexes which you are using. The first method is the best one as it avoids the unneeded indexes.

If you need both you can use enumerate() to do this

```
for index, element in enumerate(spam):
    #do stuff
```